# Redirecting some IP adresses with nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, ip, forward

How to forward few IP adresses with nginx to specific file. I use this:

```
server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;

if ($remote_addr = 123.123.123.123) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.mysite.com/somepage.php;
    }
```

How I can add [OR] some other address or I must write again IF statement?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to have many OR statements in the one IF expression.
There are two solutions for how to describe these forward rules:

## A simple solution

Use a built-in **allow** / **deny** operations to redirect many IP addresses in Nginx.

For example:

```
server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;

location / {
    error_page 403 http://www.mysite.com/somepage.php;  
    deny 123.123.123.123;
    deny 124.124.124.124;
    deny 125.125.125.125;
    deny 192.168.1.0/24;   # Deny a range of IP addresses

    # etc.

    allow all;  
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
}

location /somepage.php {
    allow all;
}
```

## A complex solution

It will require to install an additional nginx module, called [ngx_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule). Given module  allows you to use a full value programming language Lua to write a nginx configuration.

Comment: Not really sure if you can both 403 and redirect at the same time, but if it works I'd add `=200` so that the page doesn't load with an error code.

Comment: If I add 403 page then "problematic visitor" will see that I deny his IP addresses and he can attack from different IP...I wanna serve him some web page with useless content.

Comment: The "problematic visitor" will not see, because he will be redirected to the fake page (e.g. "/somepage.php"). He could understand it only by looking on the HTTP headers the nginx was added (e.i. "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily").

Comment: I must make they to think "They not updating site more so we not have interest to crawl they more"...if they see 302 they can change IP and still crawl..can I return to they 404?

Comment: I've found an interesting 3rd party module to limit flooders/grabbers by limiting a time between the requests - [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) . Maybe this will perfectly  suit to your needs - no needs to add new banned IP address manually.